# Avoiding SSH error messagers when logging into an older machine

Tags: linux, ssh, md5

Consider two machines:

- A runs an older version of Linux (e.g. 10 years old)
- B runs a new(ish) version of Linux

When I try to SSH from A to B, I succeed, but with a messages saying:

```
MD5 not allowed in FIPS 140-2 mode, using SHA-1 for key fingerprints instead.
```

I read here and there online that I should set the `FingerprintHash` option, . But - my older SSH version (the client, on A) doesn't support this this option. Can I do something else instead to ensure that an appropriate fingerprinting scheme is used - and for machine B's server not to complain?

Note: Assume I don't have root on the server; and try to avoid using root on the client if possible.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Since you are still able to successfully connect to the server, you might have to accept the message will be displayed, until you update older version of OpenSSH. It goes without saying, you really should should patch the server, to prevent malicious access to it.

Comment: @Ramhound: See edit. I just want the error message to go away. Of course I'm not going to patch the server...

Comment: It's not an error message, it's a warning, to highlight the fact the client is attempting to use an unsupported mode.  You could disable FIPS-140-2 mode at the kernel but that would require kernel configuration changes and you don't have root.  You must understand. MD5 fingerprints are not secure, and are easily defeated.

Comment: @Ramhound: I do understand this. Are you saying that my client version doesn't support any secure fingerprinting scheme?